# Upload videos with PHP and Google+ profile identity

Tags: php, youtube-api, gdata

Just a little background:

After youtube offered me to get a Google + profile for my channel I accepted.

Now, when I log on my channel's google account, it shows like I have 2 channels: the one with the name I selected, and another one empty with my e-mail.

So, I used to upload videos using the zend gdata api, so I can download files using wget on my server and avoid downloading and uploading from my pc.

After that change, whenever I try to upload a video, I get this error:

NoLinkedYouTubeAccount

As far as I know, this error comes when your youtube account is not linked to your Google Account, which is not the case here. I'm pretty sure it have something to do with the new google+ integration features.

The code I'm using is an adaptation of this -> https://github.com/JWhy/Youtube-Uploader

Note 1: I've test the script out of the box, without any changes, it doesn't work.

Note 2: I've test both scripts using a youtube account which is not linked to google+ and IT DOES work.